# How to model multi-output processes in Brightway2?

Tags: python, modeling, lifecycle, brightway

Within a cycle process (hydrogenation and dehydrogenation) I am trying to model the dehydrogenation.

Out of the activity dehydrogenation, I get two products:

1. hydrogen (my functional unit)
2. an unsaturated hydrogen carrier.

In the activity dehydrogenation, two streams go in.

1. saturated hydrogen carrier
2. heat energy.

I am using Brightway2 and Ecoinvent. My goal is to be able to reference the two outgoing streams (hydrogen and unsaturated hydrogen carriers) in subsequent exchanges or to have both stored so I can continue to use them. For example, I want to reference the exiting hydrogen from dehydrogenation in the next exchange called "compressor".

The exiting unsaturated hydrogen carrier from dehydrogenation, however, I want to be able to reference in any next exchange (in this case, the hydrogen carrier is recirculated until it is back in its saturated form).

[Flowchart of what I am trying to model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhYO7.jpg)

So far I tried solving this problem with the multifunctional package but I constantly get errors. I didn't really understand what the specific syntax needed to be in order to run the multifunctional package correctly and solve the problem.

Below I have included an excerpt of my code. Note the comments I have added.

```py
# DEHYDROGENATION ACTIVITY
for activity in [act for act in fgdb if 'Dehydrogenation' in act['name']]:
    activity.delete()

#fgdb stands for my foreground system database (basically technosphere matrix)

DHy_Sat = fgdb.new_activity(
    code = 'DHy_ns',
    name = 'Dehydrogenation',
    unit = 'kg'
)

DHy_Sat.new_exchange(
    amount = 1,
    unit = 'kg',
    input = DHy_Sat.key,
    type = 'production',
    reference_product = 'Hydrogen'
).save()

DHy_Sat.new_exchange(
    amount = -69.61, # unsaturated carrier exits DHy_Sat activity
    unit = 'kg',
    input = DHy_Sat.key,
    type = 'technosphere',
    code = 'Notsat_from_DHy',
    reference_product = 'Not Saturated Carrier'
).save()

DHy_Sat['reference product'] = 'Hydrogen'
DHy_Sat.save()

# DEHYDROGENATION EXCHANGES

DHy_Sat.new_exchange(
    amount = 70.68,
    unit = 'kg',
    input = Unloading_Sat.key,   
    type = 'technosphere'
).save() #DHy_Sat activity gets its input from a previous activity called Unloading_Sat

DHy_Sat.new_exchange(
    amount = 3600,
    unit = 'MJ',
    input = heat_for_DHy[0].key, #heat_for_DHy is taken from Ecoinvent
    type = 'technosphere'
).save()

# NOT SATURATED LOADING EXCHANGES

Loading_Notsat.new_exchange(
    amount = 69.61,
    unit = 'kg',
    input = DHy_Sat.key,      #Here I want the input to be the unsaturated carrier ‘Notsat_from_DHy’
    type = 'technosphere'
).save()

Loading_Notsat.new_exchange(
    amount = 0.01,
    unit = 'kWh',
    input = electricity_from_grid_regional[0].key, #is taken from Ecoinvent

    type = 'technosphere'
).save()

# COMPRESSOR

for activity in [act for act in fgdb if 'HP Compressor' in act['name']]: # Avoiding activity duplicates
    activity.delete()

compressor = fgdb.new_activity(
    code='compr_hp',
    name='HP Compressor',
    unit='kg'
)

compressor.new_exchange(
    amount = 42.42,
    unit = 'kWh',
    input = electricity_from_grid_regional[0].key, #comes from Ecoinvent
    type = 'technosphere'
).save()

compressor.new_exchange(
    amount = 1,
    unit = 'kg',
    input = DHy_Sat.key,
    type = 'technosphere'
).save()

compressor.new_exchange(
    amount = 1,
    unit = 'kg',
    input = compressor.key,
    type = 'production'
).save()

compressor['reference product'] = 'hydrogen'
compressor.save()
```

[Flowchart of the loop process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnfTG.png)

**Technology Matrix**

|  | Hydrogenation | Dehydrogenation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| H2 In (kg) | -0.05 | 0 |
| Sat. H2-Carrier (kg) | 1.00 | -20.00 |
| H2 Out (kg) | 0 | 1.00 |
| Unsat. H2 Carrier (kg) | -0.95 | 19.00 |

Comment: Can you add a reference to the `multifunctional` library you are using?

Comment: I tried using this [link](https://github.com/brightway-lca/multifunctional).

Comment: @ChrisMutel In this present case, I would use the physical allocation method because my unsaturated hydrogen carrier and my hydrogen have different states of matter, for example.
However, I do not understand how to provide the necessary data for this allocation method. At the very least, it would have been very helpful to me if there was some example code to help someone understand the syntax. 
Are my thoughts on the chosen allocation method understandable and correct? How would you, with my problem at hand, proceed in the simplest way?

Answer (score 0):

The `multifunctional` library you linked to is a shell, there is no working code there. Currently you need to decide how to do allocation on your own, there are as many ways to do this in Brightway as there are in LCA :)

The key is to create `product` nodes for the functional outputs of the multifunctional process(es). The multifunctional process needs to have a type other than `process` - `multifunctional` seems to work fine. This process will sit in the database but never be used when building the matrix.

You then write a function to do allocation based on whatever you want - some attributes of the multifunctional dataset, some outside data source, it is up to you. You will then store the allocated, single-output processes as normal datasets in the same database (or in another one, that doesn't matter).

Here are two notebooks doing this. I just forgot I wrote it up once so did it again:

- [Allocating datasets manually](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2/blob/master/notebooks/Allocating%20datasets%20manually.ipynb)
- [Simple manual economic allocation](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2/blob/master/notebooks/Simple%20manual%20economic%20allocation.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

This is rather a LCA question than a coding question (and I was also wondering about this multifunctional library...).

Brightway2 does not solve multi-functionality automatically. You need to 1) understand your objective and what you want to evaluate 2) consistently with this, choose a system model approach (partitioning or substitution) that answers your question, 3) solve the system accordingly (Have you tried doing this technology matrix in excel? it might be useful to do it), 4) model such matrix in brightway according to brightway syntax.

Sidenote: it's difficult to give a solution because the system described is very unclear. The "circular process" is quite mysterious. It could be modelled as a treatment activity and then you would not even have the multi-functionality problem (i.e., is unsaturated H2 carrier really a co-product?). Etc. Many ways to model this but not a brightway issue *per se*.

Comment: I am not sure if I explained my problem very well. @MassimoPizzol I think you are right, the unsaturated H2 carrier is no real co-product of my process in the sense that it would require allocation.  The H2 carrier is only looping between the hydrogenation and dehydrogenation activities (assuming that is does not degenerate). My problem is that I don’t know how to link the unsaturated H2 carrier from the dehydrogenation to the hydrogenation.

Comment: In my initial question above, I have attached a short example of my technology matrix and sketched a schematic flowchart of my loop process that I want to model in Brightway2.

Comment: Starting from this matrix. 1) add a column called "Hydrolysis" on the left of the "hydrogenation" column. the main output of this will be 1 kg of "H2 in". 2) add a column called "Production of carrier" on the right of the "Dehydrogenation" column. The main output would be 1 kg "Unsat H2 carrier". Then you have a (4 activities x 4 products) square matrix. I am using the substitution method and this system as reference: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_organic_hydrogen_carriers. You might alternatively partition the system as others have suggested.